# Не получается прижать Button к нижнему краю RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

Что-то не получается прижать кнопку и чекбокс к нижнему краю. Подскажите как прижать их к нижнему краю чтобы в самом внизу была кнопка, над ней чекбокс, а чтобы всю середину оставшуюся занимал `txtTranslation`.

Если у кнопки я пишу `layout_alignParentBottom="true"`, то она растягивается и увеличивается высота кнопки, а прижать не могу

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/rLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/backgroung"
    android:padding="@dimen/padding">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/linearlayout"
        android:padding="@dimen/padding">

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </FrameLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fLayout2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/fLayout1"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_top">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/txtWord"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/linearlayout"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Введите слово"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:padding="@dimen/padding_inputs" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btnClearForAdd"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/margin"
            android:background="@android:color/background_light"
            android:onClick="onClearBtnClick"
            android:padding="@dimen/padding"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/icon_clear" />

    </FrameLayout>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtTranslation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/fLayout2"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_top"
        android:background="@drawable/linearlayout"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Введите перевод"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:padding="@dimen/padding_inputs"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/sendCheck"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="false"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="false"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtTranslation"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_top"
        android:background="@drawable/linearlayout"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:text="Сообщить разработчику" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnAdd"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/sendCheck"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_top"
        android:background="@drawable/button_style_nocolor"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:onClick="onClickAddButton"
        android:text="Добавить слово"
        android:textColor="@android:color/background_light" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Переключитесь в режим Design и перетащите их мышью куда надо - студия легко с этим справится

Comment: Я это сделал. Но свойствами можно задать чтобы на всех экранах нормально смотрелось?

Comment: Свойства задаются в любом случае (в режиме Design студия правит их за Вас), но Вы ведь всегда можете переключиться обратно в текстовый режим и поправить всё что считаете нужным

Answer (score 2):

Вот вам небольшой сэмпл:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Spinner
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="First EditText"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Second EditText"/>

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Выглядит так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ключевой момент – использование атрибута `android:layout_weight`.

Answer (score 0):

Вашу проблему можно решить и без использования весов, которые считаются вредными с точки зрения производительности. Достаточно изменить три последних элемента:

1. Прижать кнопку к низу с помощью
   `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"`
2. Прижать чек бокс к
   кнопке сверху с помощью `android:layout_above="@+id/btnAdd"`
3. Текстовое поле растянуть между фреймлэйаутом и чекбоксом задав
   одновременно `layout_below` и `layout_above`

Результат ниже

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/txtTranslation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/fLayout2"
    android:layout_above="@+id/sendCheck"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_top"
    android:background="@drawable/linearlayout"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Введите перевод"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    android:padding="@dimen/padding_inputs"
    android:scrollbars="vertical" />
<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/sendCheck"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="false"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="false"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
    android:layout_above="@+id/btnAdd"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_top"
    android:background="@drawable/linearlayout"
    android:enabled="false"
    android:text="Сообщить разработчику" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnAdd"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_top"
    android:background="@drawable/button_style_nocolor"
    android:enabled="false"
    android:onClick="onClickAddButton"
    android:text="Добавить слово"
    android:textColor="@android:color/background_light" />
```

Кстати, у Вас одновременно задаётся и фон корневого элемента, и фон для большинства дочерних элементов, что создаёт проблему ["перерисовки"](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/rendering/overdraw.html). Возможно, Вам стоит отказаться от установки фона для корневого элемента.

А для создания текстового поля с кнопкой "очистить" лучше воспользоваться [готовым решением](https://github.com/Cielsk/clearable-edittext), которое использует `drawableLeft` вместо более затратной отрисовки нескольких `View` поверх друг друга.